# How to distinguish HTTP Request and XML HTTP Request in Node.js using express?

Tags: node.js, http, express, xmlhttprequest

In my code for some reason I want to distinguish normal HTTP Request and AJAX Request (i.e XML HTTP Request).

After searching a lot, I have tried to use `req.isXMLHttpRequest`, but for both type of Request it returns `undefined`.

Now I am handling it by adding a flag in each and every HTTP Request as `isAjax` with *true* or *false* value.

**Question:** What is the best suggested way?

1. To use adding flag (`isAJAX`) to each XML HTTP request (with *true* or *false*)
2. Find out and fix `req.isXMLHttpRequest` related issues.

Will be of great help if anyone tell me, Why `req.isXMLHttpRequest` is returning `undefined`?

Advanced Thanks

**Note:** I am using *Node.JS Version 0.8.20* and *Express Version 3.1.0*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this.

```
req.xhr
```

this will return true or false if it is an XMLHttpRequest or not.

Comment: `req.xhr` worked. But why not `req.isxmlhttprequest`. Since its documented http://expressjs.com/2x/guide.html#req.isxmlhttprequest.

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni You should use the current guide http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.xhr i think the version guide you are looking at is 2.x while you are using 3.x

Comment: Note that req.xhr simply checks for a specific request header which is _not_ automatically added to each XMLHttpRequest by the browser, but by some javascript frameworks only.

Comment: this is not the correct answer req.xhr can often return undefined on an an AJAX call.

Comment: req.xhr will return false if ajax calls initiated from IE

Comment: Doesn't work with AngularJS HttpProvider. They removed 'X-Requested-With' from header defaults about a year ago. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3a75b1124d062f64093a90b26630938558909e8d

Answer (score 1):

Following @scartag answer.
If you control whoever sending the request (e.g., it's your client code) then you can just set the HTTP header `X-Requested-With: xmlhttprequest`or change the body/url to mark the xhr request.

If you don't control whoever is sending the request you can't rely on `req.xhr` then your options depend on your use case. For instance, if you just want to respond with a content that is appropriate to the request then `res.format(_)` could be more useful than `req.xhr` (it depends on your clients, but you can probably assume that clients won't request a format that they cannot handle).