# jquery ajax post options to node.js request options

Tags: node.js

I use jQuery's ajax method in my node.js code. I would like to convert my jQuery ajax function's passed options to node's http module's request method options since now I want to use the request method instead. Is there a better way to do that than this ?

```
    function checkSetOption(param){
    if(param === undefined){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;    
    }

} // End checkSetOption
//
var ajax = function(params,callBack){

    request_options = {};

    // Parse for http request params
    params = new Array('dataType','url','method','success');
    params.forEach(function(option,index,array){
        if(checkSetOption(option)){

            request_options.option = params.option;
        }
    }); // End 'forEach' method



    http.request(param);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question correctly you want to call jquery ajax to a URL from node.js. Then you cannot use `http.request` method for this. AJAX uses `XMLHttpRequest` and http.request as the name says is that. [Both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038474/how-to-distinguish-http-request-and-xml-http-request-in-node-js-using-express) are different, so you may not be able to convert it.

Use [XMLHttpRequest](https://npmjs.org/package/xmlhttprequest) package in node for this. The [jquery](https://npmjs.org/package/jquery) module uses `XMLHttpRequest` to call AJAX.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638820/jquery-ajax-in-node-js)